# Artifacts while rendering sponza scene

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm trying to render the Sponza scene using the Cook-Torrance BRDF Model Plugged with the GGX Normal Distribution, Gemoetry Schlick and fresnel Schlick approximation and a punctual point light. When rendered I get these artifacts

[image: final scene]

I don't know why these fragments in the yellow boxes are shadowed although everything in the **Gbuffer** looks normal. Here is the **positions map**

[image: positions]

diffuse map

[image]

normal map

[image]

roughness map

[image]

metallness map

[image]

and finally the Ambient Occlusion

[image]

and here the fragment shader used to render the scene

```
#version 440 core

const float PI = 3.14159265359f;

struct PointLight 
{
    vec3 light_position;
    vec3 light_intensity;
    float radius; 
};

uniform sampler2D position_map;
uniform sampler2D normal_map;
uniform sampler2D diffuse_map;
uniform sampler2D roughness_map;
uniform sampler2D metalness_map;
uniform sampler2D ao_map;
uniform PointLight pointlight; 

in vec2 o_uv; 

out vec4 final_color; 

// NDF
float GGX_Distribution(float roughness, vec3 normal, vec3 halfway)
{
    float numerator = pow(roughness, 4.0f); 
    float NdotH = max(dot(normal, halfway), 0.0f); 
    float denominator = PI * pow((NdotH * NdotH * (numerator - 1) + 1), 2.0f);
    return numerator / denominator;
}

// Schlick-GGX
float SchlickGGX(vec3 normal, vec3 dir, float roughness)
{
    float k_numerator = roughness + 1; 
    float k = (k_numerator * k_numerator) / 8.0f; 
    float numerator = max(dot(normal, dir), 0.0f); 
    float denominator = numerator * (1.0f - k) + k;

    return numerator / denominator; 
}

float GeometrySchlickGGX(vec3 normal, vec3 lightdir, vec3 viewdir, float roughness)
{
    return SchlickGGX(normal, lightdir, roughness) * SchlickGGX(normal, viewdir, roughness); 
}

vec3 F_Schlick(vec3 F0, vec3 lightdir, vec3 halfway)
{
    float LdotH = max(dot(lightdir, halfway), 0.0f); 
    return F0 + (1.0f - F0) * pow((1.0f - LdotH), 5.0f); 
}
    
vec3 PointLightIllum(PointLight pointlight, vec3 fragPos, float roughness,
                            vec3 diffuse, float metalness, vec3 normal)
{
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(pointlight.light_position - fragPos);

    vec3 viewDir = normalize(-fragPos);
    vec3 halfway = normalize(lightDir + viewDir);
    
    float d = length(pointlight.light_position - fragPos); 
    float attenuation = 1.0f / ((d * d) + 0.001f);

    float NdotL = max(dot(lightDir, normal), 0.0f); 
    float NdotV = max(dot(viewDir, normal), 0.0f); 

    vec3 F0 = vec3(0.04);
    F0 = mix(F0, diffuse, metalness);

    // Specular Reflections
    vec3 F = F_Schlick(F0, lightDir, halfway);

    // Shadowing and masking
    float G = GeometrySchlickGGX(normal, lightDir, viewDir, roughness);
    float D = GGX_Distribution(roughness, normal, halfway);

    vec3 numerator = F * G * D; 
    float denominator = 4.0f * NdotV * NdotL + 0.0001f;
    vec3 BRDF = numerator / denominator; 

    vec3 spec = BRDF * pointlight.light_intensity * attenuation * NdotL;
    vec3 diff = (diffuse / PI) * pointlight.light_intensity * attenuation * NdotL * (1.0f - metalness); 
    diff *= vec3(1.0f) - F;

    vec3 Lo = spec + diff; 

    return Lo;
}

void main()
{
    vec3 fragPos = texture(position_map, o_uv).rgb;
    vec3 normal = normalize(texture(normal_map, o_uv).rgb);
    vec3 diffuse = texture(diffuse_map, o_uv).rgb;
    float roughness = texture(roughness_map, o_uv).r; 
    float metalness = texture(metalness_map, o_uv).r; 
    float ao = texture(ao_map, o_uv).r;

    // Ambient occlusion
    float ambient_intensity = 0.2f; 
    vec3 ambient = diffuse * ambient_intensity * ao;

    vec3 direct = PointLightIllum(pointlight, fragPos, roughness, diffuse, metalness, normal);
    vec3 indirect = ambient; 

    final_color = vec4(indirect + direct, 1.0f);
}
```

the vertex shader is a simple shader where i just render a quad with the size of screen and use its UVs to sample the textures. Could Someone tell why i'm having this artifact and how to resolve it?

Comment: Is your camera at the origin? " vec3 viewDir = normalize(-fragPos);"

Comment: yes i have a fixed camera centered at the origin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I'm embarrassed to say that but turns out the problem was with the format of the normals render target instead of making it **GL_RGB32F** I accidentally made it **GL_RGB** causing the normals to be clipped to range 0 -> 1 instead of -1 -> 1 causing some fragments to be shadowed due to incorrect lighting calculations.

Comment: Btw, you can use R10G10B10A2 format for normals to use less space than RGB32F (4 vs 12 bytes per pixel) while having more precision than with RGB8 format (10 vs 8 bits). You'll still have to manually remap normals from [-1,1] to [0,1] and back, though.